# Migrating GAE app from python 2.5 to 2.7

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to migrate my app and everything worked fine until I changed in app.yaml
from **threadsafe: false** to **threadsafe: true**.
The error I was receiving was:

**threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: a/b/xyz.app**
After some googling I found:

Only scripts in the top-level directory work as handlers, so if you have any in subdirectories, they'll need to be moved, and the script reference changed accordingly:
**- url: /whatever**
  # This doesn't work ...
  # script: lib/some_library/handler.app
  **# ... this does work

  script: handler.app**

**Is there any workaround** for this(if above research is valid), as I don't want to change my project hirarchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your handlers anywhere as long as it's a valid python import path.

My app.yaml is full of entries like

```
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.application
  login: admin
```

The folders need `__init__.py` in them to make them work as modules, but you can usually replace any `/` with `.`

Alternatively do as Daniel suggest, and note that you'll probably have to mangle the `sys.path` first to include `lib` dir and then import handler.

Answer (score 2):

Put a main file in the top-level directory and import all your handlers there, then reference them via that file